# appcmd code in C#?

Tags: c#, iis-7, powershell, appcmd

I have an web service that run's this:

```
 var Proc = new Process();
                Proc.StartInfo.FileName = CredentialBatFile;
                Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = WebSiteName + " " + Apppool_Username 
                                                    + " " + Apppool_Password;
                Proc.Start();
```

The bat file has:

```
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set site "%1" 
              -virtualDirectoryDefaults.userName:%2 
              -virtualDirectoryDefaults.password:%3
```

If I run on localhost (on the server) it works fine. however if I run it on the server from the web service it fails.

Can I achieve the same function as `appcmd` in pure C# code?

**EDIT**

```
Exception: Unknown error (0xfffffffe) StackTrace: at    
System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

Comment: I think you should show us more details about "it fails" :)

Comment: I do not know why it fails. It works perfect when I can have it debugging. However when I run it remotely (when I cannot debug it) it fails.

Comment: Since you know it fails, you must got some error messages or something.

Comment: ah, good idea. I just added a try catch, the catch will roll up the exception details so I can see it.

Comment: Exception: Unknown error (0xfffffffe) 
StackTrace:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

Comment: Posting the exception details in the question helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can. Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.virtualdirectorydefaults.username%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) example code.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar by calling the appcmd directly from c#. Adapting my case into the original question the code would be:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        Arguments = "set site \""+ WebSiteName + "\" -virtualDirectoryDefaults.userName:"+ Apppool_Username + " -virtualDirectoryDefaults.password:"+ Apppool_Password,
        FileName = "appcmd.exe",
        WorkingDirectory = @"c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\"
    });
```