# Backup IIS settings with Windows Process

Tags: c#, windows, iis

I can backup the settings of IIS with the following commands

```
//sites
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list site /config /xml > C:\Temp\iis_config_sites.xml

//apppools
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list apppool /config /xml > C:\Temp\iis_config_apppool.xml
```

When I run these commands from the Command Prompt it works fine. The XML files are created. But I wanted to automate this process by executing this command from C# code with `System.Diagnostics.Process`. For that I use the following code

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = @"list site /config /xml > C:\Temp\iis_config_sites.xml";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

But when I run this code nothing happens. The XML file is not created. But there are no errors and no warnings also. The program that executes this command runs under the Administrator account with Windows Server 2019 and IIS 10. I also tried adding `WorkingDirectory`, but that did not help either.

I use `Process` to generate a zipped folders with WinRar and that also works fine.

So if anyone knows what could be the problem that would be great.

Comment: Probably the account you use is not the correct one. Each site in IIS runs in application pool.  Each application pool has a user. These probably are the credentials you need. Pls check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584603/appcmd-code-in-c.

Comment: @Christos. The above code runs in windows itself. Not in a website's apppool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using '>' in the parameters, which is a CMD command to instruct it to write the output of command (`appcmd.exe` in this case) to specified file path (`C:\Temp\iis_config_sites.xml`).  Which of course doesn't work as the parameter of `appcmd.exe`.

You have two options:

1. To use it the following way, which is equivalent of executing the command in CMD:

   ```
   startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe";
   startInfo.Arguments = "/c \"C:\\Windows\\system32\\inetsrv\\appcmd.exe\" list site /config /xml > C:\\Temp\\iis_config_sites.xml";
   ```

   Note that the `/c` is a command line option of cmd.exe to execute the rest of parameters as a "command", just as if you entered it into command line window. The rest is just the same command which you typed in the cmd normally.
2. Use another option provided by appcmd.exe for backing up IIS that avoids the need to redirect output to file. The command is `appcmd.exe add backup %backupname%`. This command adds a backup of the IIS config and later you can restore it by `restore backup $backupname%`.